# BackupExec 2010 R3 Backup Issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, backupexec

I'm getting this strange error that re-ocours when running the daily backups, I'm using BackupExec 2010 R3 on Server 2008 R2 with Exchange 2010.

> Job ended: 29 July 2014 at 03:24:00 Completed status: Failed Final
>   error: 0xe00002f7 - Cannot extract mailbox messages from the Exchange
>   backup. Review the job log for more information. Final error category:
>   Resource Errors
>
> For additional information regarding this error refer to link
>   V-79-57344-759
>
> Backup- \EXCHANGE10\Microsoft Information Store\earthlondon
>   V-79-57344-759 - Unable to complete the operation for the selected
>   resource using the specified options for the following reason: VFF
>   Open Failure.  This can be caused by low memory or disk resources.

Any suggestions on troubleshooting?

Thanks alot

Comment: I should note that the hotfix suggested is for Backup Exec 2012

Comment: Did you refer to link V-79-57344-759? Do you have an active support/maintenance contact with Symantec?